# Place data from jsonobject into AutoCompleteTextview

Tags: android, json

I need to get data from http://schedule.sumdu.edu.ua/index/json?method=getTeachers, parse it and load into AutoCompleteTextview. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SilentKiller do not use url shorteners to circumvent intentional restrictions

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the service URL using an `AsyncTask<>`, then later on get its response into a `String` object.
And, parse it, using JSONObject/Json Array present in android. You will get many examples for this.

Later on you can create a String array, load your data in it, and set it for auto complete for text view.
Here is an example for this.

```
String[] listTeachers; // initialize this with teachers JSON data
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.layout_teacher_list, listTeachers);

tvTeacher.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: The AsyncTask is actually optional, but it definitely helps to prevent busy waits for Network IO ;)

Comment: Thank you. I i know hot to use AsyncTask and use parsing. The problem is that every json key is unique, so if i will write each id for finding teacher in my code it wiil be very big. i need to make each id for every teacher?

Comment: you can use `Map<String,String>` for this purpose, and then use the methods of Map to get array of keys. Otherwise, it will be good if you paste here what you are getting in JSON.

Comment: @manoj From json i get smth like this: {"1":"abc","2":"bcd", "3":"cde"..."4000":"abcdabcd"} As you can see it is a bad idea to write into my code every name of jsonobject value to find each value. So, a cant use any example from google like this:http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-autocompletetextview-example-json/

Comment: Yes you can. But, I need to work around and testing on it. I also don't have much knowledge with the `FilterResults`, which is used there. I will suggest, you should take that example, and create sample android project with it,  make required changes in `SuggestGetSet` and `SuggestionAdapter` class. And, see if it works. Later, you can integrate it back to your project.